# pexpect interact limiting output length

Tags: python, python-3.x, pexpect

I am running pexpect interact using pxssh to interact with an embedded device.  I use inputFilter and outputFilter to act as command parsers to interpret specific commands.

This all works OK, however i have an issue to do with the output length for each new line that is generated.

For example, if I login via ssh manually and type a command as follows, it will fill the entire terminal window before taking a new line:

```
#[PROMPT] very long command very long command very long command very long command very long command very long command very
```

long command very long command

However with pexpect running, I get the following:

```
#[PROMPT] very long command very long command very long command very long
command ve
ry long command very long command very long command very long command
```

As you can see, the command is split over multiple lines using pxpect via pxssh.

Can someone inform me why this happens and how to rectify it?

Comment: So you say your call does actually have newlines in it, and does not only appear in this way?

Comment: When the terminal output from me typing is displayed in the terminal, when using pexpect.interact it continues the command on a new line too early.  Hence my issue that the terminal output does not fill the entire width of the actual terminal

Comment: But it's only the visual appearance of the input command, isn't it? If you have a long command you normally do not type in manually, so it isn't that dealbreaking, is it? I thought of some kind of buffer error/hickup.